# C11 & C++11 Exended and Universal Character Escaping

Tags: c++, c, c++11, language-lawyer, c11

#### Context

[C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) and [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) both support extended characters in source files, as well as [universal character names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Universal_character_names) (UCNs), which allow one to enter characters not in the basic source character set using only characters that are.

C++11 also defines several translation phases of compilation. In particular,  extended characters are normalized to UCNs in the very first phase of translation, described below:

**§ C++11 2.2p1.1:**

> Physical source file characters are mapped, in an
> implementation-defined manner, to the basic source character set
> (introducing new-line characters for end-of-line indicators) if
> necessary. The set of physical source file characters accepted is
> implementation-defined. Trigraph sequences (2.4) are replaced by
> corresponding single-character internal representations. Any source
> file character not in the basic source character set (2.3) is replaced
> by the universal-character-name that designates that character. (An
> implementation may use any internal encoding, so long as an actual
> extended character encountered in the source file, and the same
> extended character expressed in the source file as a
> universal-character-name (i.e., using the \uXXXX notation), are
> handled equivalently except where this replacement is reverted in a
> raw string literal.)

---

#### Question

Does a Standard-conforming compilation of the program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
        printf("\é\n");
        printf("\\u00e9\n");
        return 0;
}
```

fail, compile and print

```
é
é
```

or compile and print

```
\u00e9
\u00e9
```

, when run?

---

#### Informed Personal Opinion

It is my contention that the answer is that it successfully compiles and prints `\u00e9`, since by §2.2p1.1 above, we have

*An implementation may use any internal encoding, **so long as an actual extended character encountered in the source file**, and **the same extended character expressed in the source file as a universal-character-name** (i.e., **using the \uXXXX notation**), are handled **equivalently** except where this replacement is reverted in a raw string literal.*, and we are not in a raw string literal.

It then follows that

- In Phase 1, `printf("\é\n");` maps to `printf("\\u00e9\n");`.
- In Phase 3, *The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens* (§2.2p1.3), of which the *string-literal* `"\\u00e9\n"` is one.
- In Phase 5, *Each source character set member in a character literal or a string literal, as well as each escape sequence and universal-character-name in a character literal or a non-raw string literal, is converted to the corresponding member of the execution character set* (§2.2p1.5). Thus, by the maximal munch principle, `\\` maps to `\`, and the fragment `u00e9` is not recognized as a UCN and therefore prints as is.

#### Experiments

Unfortunately, extant compilers disagree with me. I've tested with both [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) 4.8.2 and [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) 3.5, and here is what they gave me:

- GCC 4.8.2

  ```
  g++ -std=c++11  -Wall -Wextra ucn.cpp -o ucn
  ```

  Output:

  > ```
  > ucn.cpp: In function 'int main()':
  > ucn.cpp:4:9: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\303' [enabled by default]
  >   printf("\é\n");
  >          ^
  > ```

  ```
  ./ucn
  ```

  Output:

  > ```
  > é
  > \u00e9
  > ```
- Clang 3.5

  ```
  clang++ -std=c++11  -Wall -Wextra ucn.cpp -o ucn
  ```

  Output:

  > ```
  > ucn.cpp:4:10: warning: unknown escape sequence '\xFFFFFFC3' [-Wunknown-escape-sequence]
  >         printf("\é\n");
  >                 ^
  > ucn.cpp:4:12: warning: illegal character encoding in string literal [-Winvalid-source-encoding]
  >         printf("\é\n");
  >                  ^
  > 2 warnings generated.
  > ```

  ```
  ./ucn
  ```

  Output:

  > ```
  > é
  > \u00e9
  > ```

I have double- and -triple checked that the `é` character appears as `C3 A9` using `hexdump -C ucn.cpp`, in agreement with the expected UTF-8 encoding. I've moreover verified that a plain `printf("é\n");` or `printf("\u00e9\n");` works flawlessly, so this is not a problem of the compilers tested being unable to read UTF-8 source files.

***Who's right?***

Comment: [N3881](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n3881.pdf) discussed this issue, but I'm not aware of any action taken by the committee to address this.

Comment: @cpplearner Excellent detective work; That's exactly the kind of document I want to read. If comments were favouritable I'd star yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'é' is not a valid character to backslash escape in a string literal, and so a backslash followed by 'é' as either a literal source character or a UCN should produce a compiler diagnostic and undefined behavior.

Note, however, that `"\\u00e9"` is not a UCN preceded by a backslash, and that it's not possible to write any sequence of basic source characters in a string or character literal that is a backslash followed by a UCN. Thus `"\é"` and `"\\u00e9"` are not required to behave the same: The behavior of `"\\u00e9"` can be perfectly well defined while the behavior of `"\é"` is undefined.

If we were to posit some syntax that allowed backslash escaping a UCN, say `"\«\u00e9»"`, then that would have undefined behavior like `"\é"`.

---

> - In Phase 1, `printf("\é\n");` maps to `printf("\\u00e9\n");`.

The phase one conversion of `é` into a UCN cannot create a non-UCN, such as `"\\u00e9"`.

---

The compilers are right, but don't specifically handle this situation with perfect diagnostic messages. Ideally what you'd get is:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11  -Wall -Wextra ucn.cpp -o ucn
ucn.cpp:4:10: warning: unknown escape sequence '\é' [-Wunknown-escape-sequence]
        printf("\é\n");
                ^
1 warnings generated.
$ ./ucn
é
\u00e9
```

Both compilers specify that their behavior in the presence of an unknown escape sequence is to replace the escape sequence with the character thus escaped, so `"\é"` would be treated as `"é"` and the program overall should be interpreted as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
        printf("é\n");
        printf("\\u00e9\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Both compilers do happen to get this behavior, partially by chance, but also partially because the policy to treat unrecognized escape sequences the way they do is a smart choice: Even though they only see the unrecognized escape sequence as the backslash followed by the byte 0xC3, they remove the backslash and leave the 0xC3 in place, which means the UTF-8 sequence is left intact for later processing.

Comment: This is what baffles me from your argument: _The phase one conversion of `é` into a UCN cannot create a non-UCN, such as `"\\u00e9"`_. By the end of Phase 1, there is **no** distinction _in the compiler_ between `"é"` and `"\u00e9"`, since both are understood as `"\u00e9"`. From then on the compiler _must_ give exactly the same treatment to both, since they are the same. Phase 1 occurs _before the concept of a string/escape sequence is even understood_, so there's no reason to think it's allowed to treat `\é` and `\\u00e9` differently. Phase 1 literally pastes in `\u00e9` whenever `é` occurs.

Comment: In any case, §2.2p1.1 and numerous other places state that an extended character **in the source file** is handled _the same_ as if it were substituted with a UCN in `\uXXXX` notation **in the source file**. The compiler, in Phase 2+, cannot isolate the `\u00e9` in `"\\u00e9"` as a character unto itself just because it originated from an `é`, for the simple reason that from the perspective of those later phases, _the programmer actually **did** type_ `\\u009` - **in the source file**.

Comment: "By the end of Phase 1, there is no distinction in the compiler between "é" and `"\u00e9"`" But there is a distinction between characters "\u00e9" making up a UCN and characters "\u00e9" not making up a UCN.

Comment: The spec states that extended characters are replaced by a UCN: But that's different from being replaced by a sequence of characters that might look like a UCN but which is not, due to a preceding backslash. There's nothing that says 'é' is replaced by a sequence of characters that fails to make up a UCN.

Comment: But why? That's precisely what I argue isn't the case; Phase 1 _doesn't know_ about \\ escapes. There is no concept of failure to construct a sequence of characters that fails to make a UCN as the concept of a string or escape sequence is not yet present in this very first phase of translation : For Phase 1, `é` -> `\u00e9`, preceding backslash or not, in a comment or not. If preceding backslashes do matter, why aren't they mentioned in Phase 1's description, where it is explicitly said that the text "é" in a source file is handled _exactly_ as though the text "\u00e9" had appeared instead?

Comment: That's not what it says though. Instead of referring simply to a sequence of characters beginning with `'\'` and `'u'`, it refers to a grammar element _universal-character-name_. There's no valid way for this element to appear in this position, and you can't just reinterpret it to mean the grammar element decomposed into source characters and then re-parsed into different grammar elements. The result is a situation for which the spec does not define any behavior, which means you get _undefined behavior_.

Comment: So far this is my best lead. +1. However, "_The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens_" occurs only in Phase 3, long after Phase 1. Before Phase 3 the Standard does not speak of lexed _tokens_. It speaks of "characters" and "character sequence that matches the syntax of a _universal-character-name_" (In Phase 2). I guess you've successfully narrowed down the issue for me to whether a _universal-character-name_ in Phase 1 is to be understood as a (indivisible) character or as a (divisible) sequence of characters. I still lean towards the later but you've made me less sure.

Comment: Maybe Chris Lattner would like to pitch into this conversation? I see you've got a link to his account on your own page.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused, thinking that `\\u00e9` is a UCN -- it is not.  UCNs all begin with `\u`, and in your case, you have an extract backslash which escapes this initial backslash.  So `\\u00e9` is the sequence of 6 characters: `\`, `u`, `0`, `0`, `e`, `9`.

**edit**

> In Phase 1, printf("\é\n"); maps to printf("\u00e9\n");.

This is where you're going wrong -- Phase 1 translates input characters into source characters, so `printf("\é\n");` maps to `p` `r` `i` `n` `t` `f` `(` `"` `\` `é` `\` `n` `"` `)` `;`, which is the same as `p` `r` `i` `n` `t` `f` `(` `"` `\` `\u00e9` `\` `n` `"` `)` `;`, but that's not the same as what `printf("\\u00e9\n");` maps to because of the double-backslash in the latter.  Because of the special handling of double-backslash, there is no way to have a backslash followed by a UCN in the source.

Comment: On this point I'm certain I'm not confused; I am definitely aware that `\\u00e9` breaks down to those 6 characters. The question is whether `\é` also converts to those 6 characters (by my reading of the Standard) or to just `é`, and if so why. GCC and Clang appear to disobey the letter of the Standard here, so the question naturally arises as to why (maybe there's a section I missed?). More generally, it's about the exact place of UCNs and extended characters in translation.

Comment: They don't disobey the standard here -- there's just no translation from internal characters back into source characters like you seem to be assuming.